# How to remove gaps in C3 timeseries chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3, c3.js

I have a timeseries chart created with [C3](http://c3js.org/). The chart has time gaps in the data, and this is very noticeable with a bar chart.

Is it possible to remove the gaps? I render the chart as shown below. Notice how there's a gap between `2013-01-03` and `2013-01-06`

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        type: 'bar',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-06', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/4nar0rne/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/4nar0rne/1/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the points to be plotted uniformly instead of based on the distance between the x values, you can use a category axis instead of a timseries axis.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        type: 'bar',
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-06', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08']
        }
    }    
});
```

However do note that you lose all the advantages of having a timeseries axes (bars spaced according to the time value, ordering, etc.).

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sb5p0scL/

---

And if you want the ticks to align with the center of the label you can use axis.x.centered like so

```
...
axis: {
    x: {
       tick: {
           centered: true
       }
       ...
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rc0uhf1y/

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I want, however I'd like the ticks to align to the centre of the bars (like they do in `timeseries` charts) however have the ordering of a `category` chart.