# How to remove weekend datetime gaps from x-axis of a financial chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts, plotly, highcharts

I have a use case where I pull and plot `Forex` data in the form of `ask and bid` on the graph and this is based on `minute, hour or day candlesticks` and I am only plotting the `closing` value for `bid and ask` as a `spline`.

### Issue

The endpoints that I am using their `Forex` data feed is not available from `Friday 8pm` to `Sunday 9pm`. Let's say I have the following use case

- Plot a 200 data points (i.e. hourly candle) on the graph at a time, on new candle phase out the oldest and plot the newest
- The X-Axis is the data point's `datetime` in `UTC ISO Format`
- The Y-Axis is the value of ask and bid
- At a time the graph shows `4.1 days worth of hourly candle`

The graph is `pretty` and `smooth` when the `datetime` on `x-axis` do not have any gaps. The candle timestamps are returned in the following form

```
2018-06-29T16:00:00.000000000Z
2018-06-29T17:00:00.000000000Z
2018-06-29T19:00:00.000000000Z
2018-06-29T20:00:00.000000000Z (Friday last candle 8pm)
2018-07-01T21:00:00.000000000Z (Sunday first candle 9pm) 
2018-07-01T22:00:00.000000000Z
2018-07-01T23:00:00.000000000Z
2018-07-02T00:00:00.000000000Z
```

As soon as there is a gap (around `47-49 hours`) everything gets compressed to accommodate for the stretched part of the graph as shown below (Using [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/))

[image: Using PlotlyJS Library]

Mostly, financial graphs do not show the gap. For example, looking at the [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/USDCAD/) interactive chart you will see the following for `weekend`

[image]

If you know how to tackle this issue with open source charting libraries (excluding `TradingView`) then please share your solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

Based on my findings, you can exclude the gaps using `HighStock` of `Highcharts` library. Highcharts is open source and only free to use for `Non-commercial` use, for more details see [highcharts licensing](https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts)

### plotly.js

I initially started off with [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) because it really is a very good charting library to be honest. After I came across the `datetime gap` issue (see screenshot in question) on `x-axis` I researched for solution and came across the following issues

> https://community.plot.ly/t/tickformat-without-weekends/1286/5 (forum)
>
> https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1382 (locked github thread)
>
> https://community.plot.ly/t/x-axis-without-weekends/1091/2

As per the `Github` issue link above, this is not achievable at the moment for how the `datetime` is handled on `x-axis`. There are workaround (like 3rd link above) but, I tried some and it either didn't work or I lost some piece of information.

I came to the conclusion that even though `plotly` is a great library, it simply cannot help me in this case. If you think it does, please share your solution :)

### C3.js

After some more research of charting libraries, I give [C3.js](https://c3js.org/) a try and after editing their live demo example with `datetime` for x-axis I observed the same weekend gap issue (see below)

[image: C3.js]

I did not bother researching why and that's probably because of being based on `D3.js` just like `plotly.js`. If you think the datetime gap can be handled with `C3.js` then please feel free to share your solution.

### Highcharts

I finally came across the family of `Highxxxxx` charting library and at first look it looked so pretty and offered all the functionalities that I wanted. I tried `Highchart` and I got the same weekend gap issue

[image: Highcharts attempt]

Well, I started to think that the only solution is to `NOT TO PLOT` the `datetime` in `x-axis` at all and somehow show the datetime in `tooltip` and that seem to do the job as shown below

[image: Highcharts with x-axis]

But, being too stubborn to give up I continued my research. I really wanted to get the charting done like `TradingView` and other stock visualization.

I decided to do some more research and little did I knew that I was so so close to a solution by the very same charting library `Highcharts` and it is called `HighStock`

### Highstock of Highcharts

[HighStock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) by default takes care of the gaps as shown below

[image: HighStock of Highcharts]

I used the following piece of Javascript

```
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  Highcharts.StockChart('chart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: function () {
              console.log('Highcharts is Loaded! Creating a reference to Chart dom.')

              //store a reference to the chart to update the data series
              var index=$("#chart").data('highchartsChart');
              highchartRef = Highcharts.charts[index]; //global var

              //Initiating the data pull here
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart title'
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Ask',
        data: [],
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 7
        },
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Bid',
        data: [],
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 7
        },
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

There you have it, a gapless (not sure if it is a real word) financial chart with `datetime` x-axis for financial data.

### Libraries I did not try

I have researched but, did not try the following charting libraries

- Google charts (didn't feel right for unknown reasons)
- Chartist (didn't see much of interactivity and financial related chart types and examples
- Chartjs (same as Chartist)
- TradingView (I give up after reading their terms of use - weird clause, my point of view)
- A majority of others that lacked the level of documentation, interactivity, finance-related charts like `Plotly` and `Highcharts`.

### Final thought

I found `Highcharts` to be

1. Well documented
2. A ton of jsfiddles examples around
3. Lots of useful SO answers
4. Pretty and very functional
5. Many options
6. Easy to use

### Similar SO questions relating to `gaps`

[How can I hide data gaps in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678365/how-can-i-hide-data-gaps-in-plotly)

[HighCharts datetime xAxis without missing values (weekends)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107525/highcharts-datetime-xaxis-without-missing-values-weekends) (Highcharts)

[Remove weekend gaps in gnuplot for candlestick chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030346/remove-weekend-gaps-in-gnuplot-for-candlestick-chart) (candlestick-chart, gunplot)

[How to remove gaps in C3 timeseries chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275222/how-to-remove-gaps-in-c3-timeseries-chart) (c3/d3 - fiddles are not working so its hard to see the solution)

[How to remove weekends dates from x axis in dc js chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001544/how-to-remove-weekends-dates-from-x-axis-in-dc-js-chart) (c3.js - the gap is some gap)

Comment: how is "pay 500 dollars extra for a single feature" an acceptable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Plotly is now supporting to hide weekend and holidays in chart with help of rangebreaks. check this link:https://plotly.com/python/time-series/   go to the section:"Hiding Weekends and Holidays"

Below is section copied from this link, example is for plotly.express but it also works for plotly.graph_objects

**Hiding Weekends and Holidays**
The rangebreaks attribute available on x- and y-axes of type date can be used to hide certain time-periods. In the example below, we show two plots: one in default mode to show gaps in the data, and one where we hide weekends and holidays to show an uninterrupted trading history. Note the smaller gaps between the grid lines for December 21 and January 4, where holidays were removed. Check out the reference for more options: https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-rangebreaks

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', range_x=['2015-12-01', '2016-01-15'],
                 title="Default Display with Gaps")
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Display without Gaps**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', range_x=['2015-12-01', '2016-01-15'],
                 title="Hide Gaps with rangebreaks")
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
        dict(values=["2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"])  # hide Christmas and New Year's
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

According to [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays)

try to add this before `fig.show()`

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "sun"]), #hide weekends
    ]
)
```

or

```
fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'category'
```

Comment: the second answer worked for me! thank you @Kirill Vladi

Answer (score 3):

Using category as the xaxis type worked for me quite nicely (notice the go.Layout object):

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            type='category',
        )
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=self.price_df.index.to_series(),
                                         open=self.price_df[e.OHLCV.OPEN.value],
                                         high=self.price_df[e.OHLCV.HIGH.value],
                                         low=self.price_df[e.OHLCV.LOW.value],
                                         close=self.price_df[e.OHLCV.CLOSE.value])],
                    layout=layout)

    fig.show()
```

Comment: this worked very well! thank you @Lukas Z.

Comment: This worked very well! Another method works too is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346100/plotly-how-to-style-a-plotly-figure-so-that-it-doesnt-display-gaps-for-missing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no need to quit on Plotly. The use of rangebreaks is indeed the tool to use, but that’s one side of it. I say this because for stock data bounds aren't practical compared to values, but you would be specifying dates for many holidays per year, and most of them change from one year to the other. So use values for rangebreaks and feed it with a list of every date that you don’t have in the CSV file you are loading. In case you need a bigger push to solve this, what I mean is taking the ‘date’ column aside, looping through it, and appending dates that are not there in another list. Then you can go ***fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=mylistofdates)])***
Hope this brings you back to Plotly!

Answer (score 0):

To remove empty columns such as Weekends from Financial Data using plotly ,Use below code.

Code-

```
import plotly.express as px


#Daily Percentage change in Nifty 50 Index
daily_returns = np.log(1+df_close.pct_change())*100

fig = px.bar(daily_returns,y = "Close", orientation='v')
fig.update_xaxes( rangeslider_visible=True, rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
    ])
fig.update_layout(
    title='Nifty 50 Daily Returns in %',
    yaxis_title='Daily % Change')
fig.update_layout( xaxis_tickformat = ' %d %B (%a)<br> %Y')

fig.show()
```

Snap-

[image: Removing Weekends]

Answer (score 0):

try this, add this option into your layout :

```js
const layout = {
     // .......
     rangebreaks: [
          {
               bounds: ["sat", "mon"]
          }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**