# How remove weekends from plot using Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to remove the weekend gaps from this time series plot. The x-axis is a data time stamp. I've tried the code on this [site](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays), but can't get it to work.
See [sample file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/14BrB31zcQL8q2lMdutm1OHtSDkb7tE6-/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel) used

The data looks like this

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
|          asof         |    INSERTED_TIME    | DATA_SOURCE |    PRICE    |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:00:15 | DB          | 170.4261757 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:06:10 | DB          | 168.9348656 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:06:29 | DB          | 168.8412129 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:07:27 | DB          | 169.878796  |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:10:28 | DB          | 169.3685879 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:12:14 | DB          | 169.0787045 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-06-17   00:00:00 | 2020-06-17 12:12:33 | DB          | 169.7561092 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Plot including weekend breaks**

Using the **line** function I'm getting the plot below, with straight lines going from Friday end of day to Monday morning. Using px.scatter, I don't get the line, but I still get the gap.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

sampledf = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

fig_sample = px.line(sampledf, x = 'INSERTED_TIME', y= 'PRICE', color = 'DATA_SOURCE')
fig_sample.show()
```

[image]

**Attempt with no weekend breaks**

```py
fig_sample = px.line(sampledf, x = 'INSERTED_TIME', y= 'PRICE', color = 'DATA_SOURCE')
fig_sample.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]) #hide weekends
    ]
)
fig_sample.show()
```

[image]

Using **rangebreaks** results in a blank plot.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove weekend datetime gaps from x-axis of a financial chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180269/how-to-remove-weekend-datetime-gaps-from-x-axis-of-a-financial-chart)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. I know I must not be using rangebreaks right?

Comment: Can't I just remove the weekend from the original data and create a graph?

Comment: @r-beginners There are no weekend in that data you can check with `df["INSERTED_TIME"].dt.weekday.unique()`

Answer (score 6):

There is a limitation of 1000 rows when using `rangebreaks`
When working with more than 1000 rows, add the parameter `render_mode='svg'`

In the code below I've used the `scatter` function, but as you can see the large weekend gaps are not longer there. Additionally I've excluded the times between 11PM and 11AM

```
sampledf = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

fig_sample = px.scatter(sampledf, x = 'INSERTED_TIME', y= 'PRICE', color = 'DATA_SOURCE', render_mode='svg')
fig_sample.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        { 'pattern': 'day of week', 'bounds': [6, 1]}
        { 'pattern': 'hour', 'bounds':[23,11]}
    ]
)
fig_sample.show()
```

[image]

The values in the plot are different from the original data set, but will work with the data in the original post.
Found help [here](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays)

Comment: where would you find all options for `pattern`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `render_mode='svg'` on `px.line`

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
    
sampledf = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
    
fig_sample = px.line(sampledf, x = 'INSERTED_TIME', y= 'PRICE', color = 'DATA_SOURCE', render_mode='svg')
fig_sample.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])]
)

fig_sample.show()
```

However, for `px.timeline` or other `px.object` that don't have `render_mode` you should use :

```
dict(pattern = "hour", dvalue = 60*60*1000,values = start_of_break)
```

start_of_break is a list date of every break you want.
dvalue is the duration of each break. Here 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the x axis on the blank plot does not even have the right range, since it begins in a different year. It's hard to explain the behavior without looking at the exact data input, but you can start with a working, simpler, dataset and try to check for differences (try to plot a filtered version of the data with select points or check for differences in the `dtypes` of the DataFrame, etc).

You will see the expected behavior with a simpler dataset:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
d = {'col1': [datetime(2020, 5, d) for d in range(1, 30)],
     'col2': [d if (d + 3) % 7 not in (5, 6) else 0 for d in range(1, 30)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index('col1')

df_weekdays = df[df['col1'].dt.dayofweek.isin([0,1,2,3,4])]

f = px.line(df, x='col1', y='col2')
f.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
    ]
)
f.show()
```

[image: with breaks]

For the DataFrame without weekends, `df_weekdays`, it's a similar image:

[image]

Comment: the exact data input in included in the original post.